# Roblox Stamina Bar and Shift to run

Tags: lua, roblox

Please, can someone make step-by-step instructions with code how to make: 1. After clicked shift, character sprints, 2. Stamina Bar Gui, and if stamina is 0, character he cannot continue running until he waits 5 seconds.